# Can't find select box with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

In my spec I have

```
select call_status.name, from: 'call_status_id'
```

When I do save_and_open_page after or before this command there is

```
<select class="form-control" id="call_status_id" name="call[status_id]">
```

But when I running this test I have

```
Failure/Error: select call_status.name, from: 'call_status_id'
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find select box "call_status_id"
```

I also tried to do

```
select call_status.name, from: '#call_status_id'
```

or

```
select call_status.name, from: 'Call Status Id'
```

or

```
select call_status.name, from: 'Call Status'
```

But I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Is the select tag properly closed? Is there more than one such ID? What happens when you use `select call_status.name, from: 'call[status_id]'`?

Comment: There is no other select tags with such ID on this page.
Nothing happens, I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Did Andy Jones's answer fix the issue for you?

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping your select in a `within` block?

```
within('//divname') do
  select call_status.name, from: '#call_status_id'
end
```

I can't give you a reason why your code does not work as is -- I assume that you are 100% certain that the id exists on the page when it runs -- but this might give you a workaround; it's worked for me under similar circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with **dropdown** component of the **Semantic-UI**, that uses **select** html component and managed to solve with visible = false, as below:

```
select 'Male', from: :user_gender, visible: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a helper under support folder e.i features/support/world.rb
Add this method to in that file:

```
def select_from_chosen(item_text, options)
    page.execute_script("
      $('##{options[:from]} option').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == '#{item_text}';
      })[0].selected = true;
      $('##{options[:from]}').trigger('liszt:updated');"
    )
  end
```

Now you can use this method in the step definitions like this :

```
select_from_chosen('Select call status',from: 'call_status_id')
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use the label text value. In the example below you should use `select call_status.name, from: 'Call Status'`

```
<label>Call Status</label>
<select class="form-control" id="call_status_id" name="call[status_id]">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that I was not able to select by the label, because the ID did not match the selects id.

So when you have a select like

```
<%= form.label :user_id %>
<%= form.collection_select :user_id, movie.assignable_users, :id, :full_name  %>
```

The form attribute of the label has to match the form attribute of the select, you can check this by clicking on the label. When it is set correctly, then the input field will be selected.

The related DOM shoud look like

```html
<label for="movie_user_id">User</label>
<select name="movie[user_id]" id="movie_user_id" data-dashlane-rid="0d250b2b30fe033f" data-form-type="other">
  <option selected="selected" value="19">Kro Bo</option>
  <option value="18">Kas Brea</option>
</select>
```

Now using `select 'Kro Bro', from: 'User'` will work.

---

Regarding the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FActions:select):

> The select box can be found via its name, id, test_id attribute, or label text. The option can be found by its text.

The `id`, `name` attribute from the DOM element from above will work as well.